How do I prove that the angle between two 2d vectors depends of sign of dot product of two 2D.?
How would you prove that given two 2D vectors in the $\vec{v} = \begin{bmatrix}
           v_{1} \\
           v_{2} \\
         \end{bmatrix}$ and $\vec{u} = \begin{bmatrix}
           u_{1} \\
           u_{2} \\
         \end{bmatrix}$
Then the sign of the dotproduct $ \vec{u}\cdot \vec{v}$.
Meaning in the following situation.
$\begin{matrix} \vec{u}\cdot \vec{v} < 0 \\
\vec{u}\cdot \vec{v} > 0 \\ \vec{u}\cdot \vec{v} = 0 \end{matrix}$
Directly influences the size of the angle $\theta$ between the vector?
where the dot product in 2d is defined.
$\vec{u}\cdot \vec{v} =|\vec{u}|\cdot |\vec{v}| \cdot cos(\theta) $
It can simply be that the dot product is negativ if the angle is larger $\theta < 180 ^\circ$ and dotproduct is zero if the angle betwen the vector is 90 $^\circ$ and so on?

since you know the relation between dot product  and cos why ask?

The angle cannot be greater than $180^\circ$. But the sign of the dot product is the same as the sign of $\cos\theta$; does that help?

So the best why to argue for this just a series of examples? Need to show this to a group highschool students.

Just take $u = (1,0)$ and $v=(cos(\theta), sin(\theta)$. You can then draw the picture, do the simple math, interpret the formula for the inner product.
